# Financial functions (Excel-style) in Postgres?

Tags: excel, postgresql

Is there a way in Postgres, natively or through a package/library, to execute financial formulas equivalent to those in Excel or Google Sheets? The one I am immediately in need of is [FVSCHEDULE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fvschedule-function-bec29522-bd87-4082-bab9-a241f3fb251d), though I'm curious about [the broader range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/financial-functions-reference-5658d81e-6035-4f24-89c1-fbf124c2b1d8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) as well.

Comment: Pgnumerics doesn't have FVSCHEDULE specifically, but it does have a lot of the functions used in Excel...  maybe you could start with this and build off of them?  It does have many of the functions listed from your link.

Comment: @Hambone sounds like Pgnumerics would be a great jump start, but I can't find it - do you have a link? I saw a link from one of your previous posts to pgnumerics.projects.postgresql.org, but that looks dead?

Comment: NEITHER CAN I...  wow, isn't that something?  Wow, let me dig deeper.

Comment: Turns out I downloaded it once upon a time from PgFoundry, which is apparently now defunct.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgfoundry.  That said, I still use the functions daily, so I know the code still works.  I suppose I can just export the DDL; you should be able to execute it and be done with it...  maybe post it to Dropbox or something.  What a shame; these are incredibly useful functions.

Comment: @Hambone Dropbox would be great if you are willing

Comment: Does this work?  There are some grants you probably need to omit, but otherwise this is all of the DDL.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QMn5-xsMf0zGkDZ9flIWCkLEPxNy_dLl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looking good! Thanks much